# add scope to form select in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a select field in an `active_admin` form which is an associated activerecord relation `Travel` and I would only like the travels to appear that have a `status = "active"`. Any idea how I can create a scope for this to be used only on the active record form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on [README](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/README.md), ActiveAdmin uses [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) to build forms.
In [Formtastic docs](http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic), you can see, under **Usage** title, how to work with collections.

So, in your `Travel` model you need a scope (or maybe, a class method returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation`)

```
class Travel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :actives, where(status: 'active')
end
```

Then in your **ActiveAdmin form** you can use that scope on `:collection` option

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "a nice title" do
    f.input :travel_id, as: :select, collection: Travel.actives
  end
end
```

Maybe you will need to format the scope results. Doing something like this:

```
Travel.actives.map{|t| [t.name,t.id]}
```